# How to execute .sql file in spark using python

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Test").set("spark.driver.memory", "1g")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

results = sqlContext.sql("/home/ubuntu/workload/queryXX.sql")
```

When I execute this command using: `python test.py` it gives me an `error`.

> y4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o20.sql.
>   : java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``with'' expected but `/' found

/home/ubuntu/workload/queryXX.sql

```
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

I am very new to Spark and I need help here to move forward.

Answer (score 12):

`SqlContext.sql` expects a valid SQL query not a path to the file. Try this:

```
with open("/home/ubuntu/workload/queryXX.sql") as fr:
   query = fr.read()
results = sqlContext.sql(query)
```

Answer (score 4):

Run `spark-sql --help` will give you

```
CLI options:
 -d,--define <key=value>          Variable subsitution to apply to hive
                                  commands. e.g. -d A=B or --define A=B
    --database <databasename>     Specify the database to use
 -e <quoted-query-string>         SQL from command line
 -f <filename>                    SQL from files
 -H,--help                        Print help information
    --hiveconf <property=value>   Use value for given property
    --hivevar <key=value>         Variable subsitution to apply to hive
                                  commands. e.g. --hivevar A=B
 -i <filename>                    Initialization SQL file
 -S,--silent                      Silent mode in interactive shell
 -v,--verbose                     Verbose mode (echo executed SQL to the
                                  console)
```

So you can execute your sql script like this:

`spark-sql -f <your-script>.sql`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure will it answer your question. But if you intend to run query on existing table you can use,

```
spark-sql -i <Filename_with abs path/.sql>
```

One more thing, if you have pyspark script you can use spark-submit details in [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).