# Spark SQL - Options for deploying SQL queries on Spark Streams

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm new to Spark and would like to run a Spark SQL query over Spark streams.

My current understanding is that I would need to define my SQL query in the code of my Spark job, as this snippet lifted from the Spark SQ home page shows:-

```
spark.read.json("s3n://...")
  .registerTempTable("json")
results = spark.sql(
  """SELECT * 
     FROM people
     JOIN json ...""")
```

What I want to do is define my query on its own somewhere - eg. .sql file - and then deploy it over a Spark cluster.

Can anyone tell me if Spark currently has any support for this architecture? eg. some API?

Comment: you are using python right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use python with open to fill your purpose:

```
with open('filepath/filename.sql') as fr:
    query = fr.read()
x = spark.sql(query)
x.show(5)
```

you could pass `filename.sql` as an argument while submitting your job using `sys.argv[]`

Please refer this link for more help: [Spark SQL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32961254/how-to-execute-sql-file-in-spark-using-python)

Comment: Hi, not exactly what I was looking for but you answered the question. Thanks.

Comment: can you specify your question so that I could give you the exact anwer?