# Calling .hql file direclty from spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hiveql

I was trying to run hql files like below , but getting error noviablealtexception

```
val QUERY = fromFile(s"$SQLDIR/select_cust_info.hql").getLines.mkString
sqlContext.sql(s"$QUERY").show()
```

Can you please help , how to run it ?

as requested the select_cust_info.hql would be like this

---

```
set hive.execution.engine=mr;
    --new records
    insert into cust_info_stage 
    select row_number () over () + ${hiveconf:maxid} as row_id , name, age, sex, country , upd_date, create_date
    from ${hiveconf:table} r
    left join  cust_dim d on id=uid
    where not  exists ( select 1 from cust_info c where c.id=r.id);

    --upd record 
    insert into cust_info_stage 
    select row_id , name, age, sex, country , upd_date, create_date
    from ${hiveconf:table} r
    inner join cust_info_stage on 
    left join  cust_dim d on id=uid
    where not  exists ( select 1 from cust_info c where c.id=r.id);
    !quit
```

---

above hql is just a sample, I want to call such hqls from sqlContext.

Now next level that I will check is , if the .hqls have hiveconf defined within, how to pass those variables in sqlContext.

Comment: how does your hql look like? Does it have comments? Which line is throwing the error? Please produce a [mcve] for us to work with. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute .sql file in spark using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32961254/how-to-execute-sql-file-in-spark-using-python)

Comment: sir added as requested , hql can be huge , 200 lines etc-.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code to run hql file in pyspark v2+

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc =SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
with open("/home/hadoop/test/abc.hql") as fr:
    query = fr.read()
    print(query)
    results = sqlCtx.sql(query)
```